# If the B-screw is too loose, would it significantly increase wear?

Tags: derailleur-rear, noise

After installing an 11-34 cassette, it makes a grinding noise even though the B screw is all the way in. The grinding sound happens only when using the largest gear. Does the grinding sound mean that one of the jockey wheels is being damaged?

I use it only on steep hills which means most of the time I won't hear it. Once my fitness improves, I plan to switch it to a smaller one.

Comment: Are you on the smallest front chainring?  That could help by reducing chain tension on the lower chainpath.

Comment: @Criggie Yes. Should I add more links?

Comment: No, adding more links will not help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like your Rear Derailleur simply can't cope with a 34 tooth rear cog.  You could replace the cassette with a 32 or 30 tooth maximum, perhaps find a smaller upper jockey wheel, or simply don't use the 34 tooth gear without drastic need.

My folder has similar problems with on its largest cog because the top jockey wheel is interfering with the cassette.  The teeth in the jockey wheel (pulley) directly touch the cassette's teeth.  I simply put up with it, because both are wear items and will be replaced in due course.

Comment: It can't cope with it. Are there harms with using it?

Comment: @Han-Lin if your chain is on another cog, its fine.   If your chain is on the big cog then the teeth are colliding through the holes in the chain.  This will be causing accelerated wear of that cog and of your top jockey wheel/pulley.  So yes there is harm in using it, in terms of increased wear.

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that it is the upper pulley that rubs against the cassette, you may want to explore these two options.

1. Install a longer B-screw. There are several vendors on the market, just google it. It is relatively cheap, and I suspect one could find a working bolt with thread pitch and diameter in a local hardware store for even cheaper.
2. Install an MTB Goatlink's equivalent which is called Roadlink. Wolf Tooth components make one, and it is not cheap.

[[image: 2]]

Basically it will move your whole derailleur farther from the cassette.

[image: Goatlink in action]

Comment: 1a.: As a workaround you can reverse the B-screw so that the screw head touches the derailleur hanger (you have to take of the rear derailleur for this). This gives you another 2mm or so of length.